# How to watch directive attributes changes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-watch

I have a directive:

### set-bid.js

```
app.directive("setBid", ($rootScope, Http, Toast) => {
  return {
    template: require('./set-bid.html'),
    scope: {
      newOrder: "<"
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

      console.log(`$scope.newOrder:`, $scope.newOrder); // undefined

    }
  }
});
```

### set-bid.html

```
{{newOrder}} <!-- nothing -->
```

### parent.html

```
<set-bid new-order="newOrder"></set-bid>
```

As you can see, I send `newOrder` variable to the `set-bid` directive.
However `newOrder` will be filled async.

I want the `set-bid` directive to watch for changes in this attribute.
But I do not want to watch on each param like this:

```
$scope.$watch("newOrder", newOrder => console.log(newOrder));
```

This is tedious. I want that the whole directive will listen for changes in every 
param that it receives. Automatically. How this can be done?

I know I can do something like this: `<set-bid ng-if="newOrder" ...></set-bid>` but I need the variable to continously be watched, not just for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Set the third argument to `true`:

```
$scope.$watch("newOrder", newOrder => console.log(newOrder), true);
```

That creates a "deep" watch.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope `$Watch` Depths](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-depths)

[image]

Comment: I don't think he is looking for a deep watch but rather a way to watch multiple params of a directive without listing them.

Comment: I am asking if those properties can be watched anyway, without define this line at all. I know about the deep watching.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass one object instead of many params and watch this one (deeply). Then, you also don't have the problem that the watcher fires multiple times, even though you e.g. just wanted to switch all params together.

Another approach would be to use a [`$watchCollection()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection) and watch multiple params together, but you would need them to be listed one by one.